# php - rand() between the same values

Tags: php, random

I havn't found a solution for this.

I have the numbers 3 and 5.
**How do I randomly choose one of those two numbers.**

In PHP.
rand() or mt_rand() jsut has min and max parameters.

thank you for your help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Or just `print [3,5][rand(0,1)];`

Comment: If you like ternary operators, there's always `print rand(0, 1) ? 3 : 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a random number with `rand()` and set `$value` to it's new value depending on the random number.

```
$value = rand(0,1) == 0 ? 3 : 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(mt_rand(0,1)) {
    echo 3;
} else {
    echo 5;
}
```

Or reverse it, your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a rand between only 2 values then use an if. So:

```
$randval = rand(0,1);
if($randval == 0)
    $value = 3;
else
    $value = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that you have 2 values so you can do something like this:

```
$rand = rand(1,2);
if ($rand == 1)
    $val = 3;
else
    $val = 5;
```